# repeating a string using a multiplier vs range()

Tags: python

The following is the question I'm presented:

> Given a string and a non-negative int n, return a larger string that
>   is n copies of the original string.
>
> string_times('Hi', 2) → 'HiHi'
>
> string_times('Hi', 3) → 'HiHiHi'
>
> string_times('Hi', 1) → 'Hi'

my solution for this is:

```
def string_times(str, n):

  if str and n >= 0:
   return str*n
```

the result came back as:

```
Expected    Run     
string_times('Hi', 2) → 'HiHi'          
string_times('Hi', 3) → 'HiHiHi'      
string_times('Hi', 1) → 'Hi'     
string_times('Hi', 0) → ''          
string_times('Hi', 5) → 'HiHiHiHiHi'            
string_times('Oh Boy!', 2) → 'Oh Boy!Oh Boy!'           
string_times('x', 4) → 'xxxx'   

string_times('', 4) → ''    None    X     <-- issue 

string_times('code', 2) → 'codecode'      
string_times('code', 3) → 'codecodecode'
```

Edit:

this is the expected result:

```
string_times('', 4) → ''
```

and this is the actual result (as I'm given)

```
string_times('', 4) → None
```

From what I can see, I'm missing the "null" part of the equation.

The solution given is the following:

```
def string_times(str, n):
  result = ""
  for i in range(n):  # range(n) is [0, 1, 2, .... n-1]
    result = result + str  # could use += here
  return result
```

My question is, in my solution does the fact that nothing*4 give nothing?

Also, can you please explain how using the built in range() function would be a more elegant solution?

Comment: What do you mean by `string_times('', 4) → ''    None    X     <-- issue`?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post picture. I'm merely copy and pasting the result chart.  Basically, the result returns as incorrect. I will update the question for more clarity

Comment: Why do you even have that `if` statement?

Comment: I'm pretty new to python so I am not sure what the best way is to write this. Can you please make some edits as give some reasoning behind it? it would be very useful for me in learning.  Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the following:

```
def string_times(str, n):

  if str and n >= 0:
   return str*n
```

Where the string is empty, then the `if` never returns a value and the functions falls off the end, returning `None` - either add a `return ''` to explicitly return blank, or just remove the check entirely...

Your entire function can just be:

```
def string_times(text, n): 
    return text * n
```

Any string multiplied by 0 or less will be an empty string, any empty string multiplied by anything will remain empty... Everything else will work as expected... I'd also not call it `str` (best to not shadow builtins) - `text` is a better choice which has been used above.